# Please Help! AUTO SHUT DOWN when sending funds from Monero GUI connected to Trezor

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, trezor

I've set up my Trezor through the Monero GUI.  I've sent funds to the account.  I tested it twice.  Worked great.

Went to send funds to a different account and every time it starts 'creating transaction' it closes the app.

Using bootstrap setup but it says 100% of chain downloaded at this point.

Would like to get the funds off this drive.

Any ideas? Please help.

Comment: most recent version 16.0.2 on osX

Comment: Reinstalled Monero GUI and rebooted it from Trezor. With Simple Node to check quickly if send is working.  Funds are still there which is good. Still cannot send funds.

Comment: I received 3 transactions in first account, before being unable to send out of account.

Comment: It's still in boostrap, and still can't send payment from device without it shutting down while creating transaction.

Comment: Any more ideas?

Comment: Do you have the latest Trezor firmware?